# How to sum very large numbers to 1 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

So imagine I have

```
>>> a = 725692137865927813642341235.00
```

If I do

```
>>> sum = a + 1
```

and afterwards

```
>>> sum == a
True
```

This is because a is bigger than a certain threshold.

Is there any trick like the `logsumexp` to perform this?

PS: **`a`** is an `np.float64`.

Comment: If these are `int`egers, use `int`. In Python-3.x, `int`s have arbitrary size.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem but a needs to be a float.

Comment: There can't be a trick -- Python float simply cannot represent both N and N+1 for sufficiently large values of N. The only "trick" might be to use a different data type: `int` or `decimal.Decimal` for example.

Comment: Does `a` have to be some sort of floating point/decimal value, or does it have to be the _type_ `float`?

Comment: Try printing out `a`.  And take a look at what you get for `725692137865927813642341235.00 == 725692137865927800000000000.00`.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` has to be specifically of type `float`, no, then that's not possible. In fact, the imprecision is much greater:

```
>>> a = 725692137865927813642341235.00
>>> a + 10000 == a
True
```

However, there are other data types that can be used to represent (almost) arbitrary precision [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) values or [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html).

```
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(a)
>>> d + 1 == d
False
>>> f = fractions.Fraction(a)
>>> f + 1 == f
False
```

(Note: of course, doing `Decimal(a)` or `Fraction(a)` does not magically restore the already lost precision of `a`; if you want to preserve that, you should pass the full value as a string.)

Answer (score 2):

0) `import decimal`
1) setup appropriate precision of the `decimal.getcontext()` ( `.prec` attribute )
2) declare as **`decimal.Decimal()`** instance

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec
28
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 300
>>> dec_a = decimal.Decimal( '725692137865927813642341235.0' )
```

It is a pleasure to use decimal module for extremely extended numerical precision solvers.

---

### BONUS:

Decimal module has very powerful context-methods, that preserve the `decimal`-module's strengths **`.add()`**, **`.subtract()`**, **`.multiply()`**,  **`.fma()`**, **`.power()`** so as to indeed build an *almost*-infinite precision solver methods ...

Definitely worth mastering these `decimal.getcontext()` methods - your solvers spring into another league in precision and un-degraded convergence levels.

Comment: You'll lose precision converting `a` to a float before casting it to a decimal.. This is true: `decimal.Decimal(725692137865927813642341235.00) == decimal.Decimal(725692137865927813642341236.00)`

Answer (score 0):

Will dividing a by 100,000 then adding 1 then times it back up again?
Eg.

```
a=725692137865927813642341235.00
a /= 100000
a += 0.00001
a *= 100000
```

Comment: This doesn't add 1, it adds 100000

Comment: This won't work because floats have a fixed number of bits for the mantissa. Multiplying only changes the exponent

Comment: Okay. Just an idea I had.